# C# - Discord Bot inconsistently sending private messages

Tags: c#, message, discord.net

I have a discord bot which sends private messages. Once I tried doing this command on my main discord account and it worked, and on my other account, it didn't work. I tried doing this again on my main account (I restarted the bot beforehand) and it didn't work. I also have a problem where I can't execute commands just by PM'ing the bot. Here is my code for a command that I am trying to use.

```
[Command("accounts",RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
        public async Task AccountsCommandHelp()
        {
            var user = UserAccounts.UserAccounts.GetAccount(Context.User);
            user = UserAccounts.UserAccounts.GetAccount(Context.User);
            string p = user.prefix;
            string message = "**Commands:**\n" +
                $"**{p}account stats @useryouwanttogetthestatsof** Gets the stats of the specified user. You don't have to specify a user. By default, the user specified is yourself \n \n" +
                $"**{p}account sendmsg** Disables some messsages the bot sends.";

            if (!Logic.IsPrivateMessage(Context.Message))
            {
                var h = Context.User.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync();
                SocketDMChannel c = await h as SocketDMChannel;
                await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
                if (user.likesToSendMessages)
                {
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":white_check_mark: Sent you a DM with information :)");

                }
                await c.SendMessageAsync(message);
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: It seems a bit unnecessary to execute the `GetAccount` twice here

Comment: Oram, I have no exceptions. MX D I removed one GetAccount code, but I still can't PM the bot to do a command.

Comment: @ChristopherIsFun Could you show your Command Handler?